How do I disable the inline execution arrow?
How do I disable this arrow? I want to keep the one on the left just not the one that's inline with the code.
Apparently I need to add more text to this question before I can submit. I think it should be self-explanatory with the image but now I've typed more.


Which language are you using? You can try to disable the related extension or dig into the extension behavior.

JS. I'm not using any extensions.

Adding noise to your post to bypass the minimum length report is a violation of the site guidelines, as well as a show of total disrespect to the millions of users of this site who put effort into keeping its quality high.

I don't think this is possible at the time of this writing. The closest thing is debug.showInlineBreakpointCandidates, but you'd want something like debug.showInlineBreakpointCurrentStackframe.
There isn't even a separate colour customization point for the inline one. It's shared as debugIcon.breakpointCurrentStackframeForeground.
I'd suggest raising a feature-request issue ticket.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
